# Access forms from another website using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, web-scraping

How can i use NodeJS to update forms from someone else's website?

example) A forum website lets you make posts with no account, how can i use nodeJS to write what i want to post as a string, then submit it to the forum using nodeJS?

example of code from 3rd party website:

```
<form id="msg" class=" msgc" method="post" action=" " enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="texter" />
<input type="submit" id="submitter" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried out  `playwright`?. It's a browser automation library.
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Axios and a post request. Anyways I don't think that it actually works if they have properly set the CORS policy.

```
axios.post('/user', {
firstName: 'Fred',
lastName: 'Flintstone'
 })
     .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
})
     .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

See [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: thank you, i decided to go with python instead since it made more since for the project. but i tested your answer and it was correct. i appreciate your help.